# Is there a way to get a list of items from a Javascript call in Python using selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

So I have recently found out that you can execute JavaScript in browsers using Selenium in Python. I have a function that returns a list of items that looks like this:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('example');
elements = [...elements].map(el => el.children[0].children[0].getAttribute('href').toString());
```

Executing this in the Browser console gets you a list of all `href`-s of the grandchildren of every element which has a `class` of example.

Is it possible to do something like this using either direct Javascript-calls or built-in Selenium functions?

Comment: share the url you try to scrape

Comment: The URL is <https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list> and the class name is `lv-info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all the href values to python you could try the following:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".example > *:first-of-type > *:first-of-type[href]")
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
```

Or, if you just want to call a js code on the browser in a single-line call:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("<your_website>") 

driver.execute_script("console.log('myElements', Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('example')).map(elm => elm.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.getAttribute('href').toString()))")
```

Comment: I know this isn't part of the question but how would I have to modify the first code snippet so it doesn't return the `href` of the grandchildren but of the element with the class itself?

Comment: You just need to call the getAttribute('href') on the elm itself, like `map(elm => elm.getAttribute('href')`  or in the first case: `find_elements_by_css_selector(".example[href]")`

Answer (score 0):

to get the `children's` `href` in native Selenium, `equivalent` to your code, it'd be something like this :

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("example xpath")
for ele in elems:
    link = ele.find_element_by_xpath(".//child::*").get_attribute('href')
    print(link)
```